# React app listen for object mutation and execute action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, actioncable

Preface: I've googled this and can't find a solution that works for me. If there is a solution on stackoverflow, my search hasn't found it.

I am using the actioncable-js-jwt library in React, and I am trying to implement warning the end user when a websocket connection disconnects and can't reconnect. What I am finding is that the Connection cable object returned on creating a cable mutates that object. Specifically I care about the `cable.connection.disconnected` and `cable.connection.monitor.reconnectAttempts` fields.

The code to create a cable looks like:

```
export const createCable = (token) => {
  const c = createConsumer(pathHelper('/cable'), token);
  console.log(c);
  return c;
};
```

I am having trouble triggering a warning based on the object change, since it mutates the object instead of returning a new object. At first I tried using `useState` & `useEffect` on the cable object, but useEffect wasn't being triggered because it doesn't rerender on object mutation.

Next I tried using MutationObserver, but found that it only works on a DOM node - not on a pure js object.

Then I tried using Proxy(), like such:

```
const [disconnected, setDisconnected] = useState(null);
const [reconnectAttempts, setReconnectAttempts] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(disconnected);
  console.log(reconnectAttempts);
}, [disconnected, reconnectAttempts]);

...(later on in the code)...
const newCable = createCable(token);
const proxy = createProxy(newCable);
setDisconnected(proxy.connection.disconnected);
setReconnectAttempts(proxy.connection.monitor.reconnectAttempts)
```

Where the createProxy() method looks like:

```
  const createProxy = (cable) => {
    const targetProxy = new Proxy(cable, {
      set(target, key, value) {
        console.log(`${key} set to ${value}`);
        target[key] = value;
        return true;
      },
      get(target, property) {
        return target[property];
      },
    });

    console.log(targetProxy);
    return targetProxy;
  };
```

However, what I am finding is that targetProxy object doesn't seem to be getting updated. The cable.connection.disconnected field is initially set to true on cable creation, then later on gets changed to false. `` console.log(`${key} set to ${value}`) `` is never logged out, and the state `disconnected` never changes after the initial value of true is set. Likewise, cable.connection.monitor.reconnectionAttempts is initially 0 but increases once the cable disconnects, and the state `reconnectionAttempts` never changes after the initial set to 0.

Ideally what I want to have happen is when disconnected = true and reconnectAttempts > 5, a warning is shown to the end user. But I'm stuck on catching when these object values change.

Comment: I think your Proxy-based solution doesn't work because it proxies `newCable` but newCable is used a direct reference by the library, it is not touching the Proxy, only code touching `proxy` directly would. In your case it seems like you either need to monkey patch the library, find a better API in it or use setInterval/requestAnimationFrame and detech the field change yourself.

Comment: Also look into whether `connection.monitor.visibilityDidChange` is something you could wrap: https://github.com/wolak88/action-cable-react-jwt/blob/master/actioncable-js-jwt.js#L133. You could Proxy that and then replace the field on the class with the proxy you created and the class should call it. Or even proxy the whole monitor field value…

Comment: Thank you so much @TomášHübelbauer. I took your suggestion of using setInterval() to detect a field change, and this let me accomplish what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I took the suggestion of Tomas Hubelbauer and added a setInterval(), which solved my problem. I now poll the cable object every 5 seconds and if the condition is true, a warning is shown.

The code now looks like:

```
const [cable, setCable] = useState(null);
const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);
const [showWebsocketConnectError, setShowWebsocketConnectError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showWebsocketConnectError) clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [showWebsocketConnectError, intervalId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (intervalId !== null) clearInterval(intervalId);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (cable.connection.disconnected && cable.connection.monitor.reconnectAttempts > 4) {
        setShowWebsocketConnectError(true);
      }
    }, 5000);
    setIntervalId(interval);

    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [cable]);

...(further down in the code)

const newCable = createCable(catToken);
setCable(newCable);
```